# Difference between Confluent.Kafka vs Confluent.Kafka.StrongName nuget packages

Tags: .net, apache-kafka

What is the difference between  Confluent.Kafka and Confluent.Kafka.StrongName nuget packages.
When to use and which one?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between those packages is that one is Strong named and the other doesn't.

The content is the same.

To fully understand what a strong name assembly is, check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/strong-named) microsoft documentation.

Here a bit of explanation:

> Strong-naming an assembly creates a unique identity for the assembly,
>   and can prevent assembly conflicts.
>
> When you reference a strong-named assembly, you can expect certain
>   benefits, such as versioning and naming protection. In the .NET
>   Framework, strong-named assemblies can be installed in the global
>   assembly cache, which is required to enable some scenarios.

If you don't know what a Strong Name assembly is, probably you have to use `Confluent.Kafka` and not the strong name version.

Comment: Confluent.Kafka is also a strong named assembly. It has a public key token and I can add the same to GAC.